# UserDetails.equals() not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have seen that, if I want to activate the concurrency-control in spring security, I have to add:

```
 <security:session-management>
     <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
 </security:session-management>
```

To the `applicationContext` and:

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

to `web.xml`.

I have done that. I have also overriden `hashCode` and `equals` in my implementation of UserDetails, but I still can login twice. I have found that, during the login process, `hashCode()` is called, but `equals()` is never called.

I don't know how it should work or when `equals()` should be called, could anybody help me with this, please?

EDIT:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherUser) {
   if (otherUser.hashCode() == hashCode())
       return true;

   return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return loginUsername.hashCode() ;
}
```

Comment: How does your `hashCode` look like?

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: You know that hash codes can be equal even when the objects are not, don't you?

Comment: @zeroflagL That is not the problem. Equals is not being called. If the hashcodes were equal, that would be another problem, but that is not relevant since no one seems to be comparing them. Also, what is supposed to happen is that the hashcodes are NOT equal, that is why it allows two sessions of the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that, when you have an authentication filter, you need to declare a ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, such as:

```
<bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
<constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
<property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
<property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"
</bean>
```

And between `<http></http>`

```
<security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER"
            ref="concurrencyFilter" />

<security:session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />
```

It is fixed now. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It may actually be working.  When I last experimented with this, I found that the second login was allowed, and the session belonging to the first login was destroyed.

Try this and see if it is working.  If that isn't the behavior you desire, then you might have to look into the documentation to see if it can be controlled via configuration.

Comment: Yes, i know that is a possibility, but that is supposed to be fixed using "error-if-maximum-exceded=true". Anyway, bth sessions are active at the same time. But thank you anyway. Iw ill keep on working on this.